# Sorting array with dates with asort() does not work properly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is the unsorted array, in the format dd-mm-yyyy:

```
array(6) { 
["7-0"]=> string(10) "28-04-2014" 
["7-1"]=> string(10) "29-04-2014"
["7-2"]=> string(10) "30-04-2014" 
["7-3"]=> string(10) "01-05-2014" 
["7-5"]=> string(10) "26-04-2014" 
["7-6"]=> string(10) "27-04-2014" 
}
```

I am now using sorting:

```
array(6) { 
["7-3"]=> string(10) "01-05-2014" 
["7-5"]=> string(10) "26-04-2014" 
["7-6"]=> string(10) "27-04-2014" 
["7-0"]=> string(10) "28-04-2014" 
["7-1"]=> string(10) "29-04-2014"
["7-2"]=> string(10) "30-04-2014" 
}
```

By using asort() to sort the array by the value, but ofcouse the 01 now comes first up. Is there any way for me to solve this easy way? It should be last in the array, hence its in the next month. (01-05-2014)

Update:

Above was the var_dump() response before and after the asort(). Below is the code snippet. After different attempts, asort() has worked fine until this week where its about the end of the month - then the array does not get sorted correctly.

```
$openhours_select = array();
foreach($openhours as $oh)
{
        $d = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('this ' . $days[$oh['fromDay']]));

        $openhours_select[$oh['id']] =$d;

}

asort($openhours_select);
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried. Can't help you fix it if we can't see it. I have code ready to go but won't post until i see some effort.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The dates **ARE** sorted, because they're strings. You'll note that the days are all in ascending order. if you want an actual date-specific sorting, you'd need to use `usort()` and provide your own comparison function.

Comment: I have provided some more explanation

Comment: Marc B, I know they are sorted - but I am looking for a solution that can sort them after the actual dates within the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those dates are not in a good format for sorting. You should store dates in ISO-8601 format which are easy to sort and then reformat when needed.

But to work around this you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to read in the date into a comparable format and then sort them.

```
uasort($openhours_select, function($a, $b) {
    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $a);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $b);
    return $date1 > $date2;
});
```

Comment: I like the solution, but I am losing the key indexes

Comment: @minitech If they want to maintain their keys that's what we'll need. Updating my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Need to get it into a better format that will sort based on actual date:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', $array), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32e298fbd6d1ba98bf44749edd8c26f435713bec)

Comment: For future readers of this answer, this only works if the date separator is a dash. If it is a slash `strtotime()` will assume MM/DD/YYYY and give back incorrect results.

Comment: Yes, US convention is `MM/DD` and Euro/other is `DD-MM`, so if conventions are held all is well. But still better to use YYYYMMDD or the same with delimiters, then it sorts as is with no nonsense.